# Reading Parameters from URL

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, query-string

I been googling to find a way to read parameter value from URL but no success. In ASP.NET Webform we used to do Request.Querystring["name"] to get the value. How to do this in MVC3?

I need to access parameter in HtmlHelper class. Anyone please.

There is no clear answer on the internet for this. Strange...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I still use  `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString` in MVC3...

```
if (!Request.QueryString["ParameterName"].IsEmpty())
{
  // Do something only if URL parameter "ParameterName" is not empty...
}
```

For example:

http://192.168.1.106:7777/Measurement?sort=FatPercentage&sortdir=DESC

```
if (!Request.QueryString["sort"].IsEmpty())
{
  // sort=FatPercentage. It's not empty and this code block will be executed
}
```

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi , I still can not get parameter value :(

Comment: @pirzada: What's the problem? Any error message? What's going on?

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi , I get null value although there is a name parameter in the URL. if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].IsEmpty())
  {
      var a = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["name"].;
  }

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Why not define two string parameters called "sort" and "sortdir" in your action method? Then you can check for emptyness with (sort == "") or some other method.

Comment: @Marcelo Zabani: I'm just trying to show an example to illustrate how to check for a querystring parameter...

Comment: @pirzada: can you show me one URL and its parameters that you are trying to read?